# Eclipse Php neon exit code= 13 HEEELLPP

Tags: eclipse

I seem to have a problem (the title explains)... I've done research but I didn't find anything about Eclipse Php neon UPDATED... So... Here's my eclipse file. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBdzu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have a 64-bit Eclipse and are trying to use a 32-bit JRE. Exit code 13 is a problem been well covered by countless other posts. They have to match.

Comment: What do I change?